# C# Outlook Shared Mailbox get subfolders intermittent

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, shared

I'm trying to get list of folders and sub-folders in a shared mailbox in outlook. Use Cached Exchange Mode and Download shared folders were both checked. 
Folders are up to 3 levels: Inbox=>Company=>ABC Company . Below is my code.

`myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();`

```
            ns = myApp.Session;
            stores = ns.Stores;

            for (int i = 1; i <= stores.Count; i++)
            {
                var _store = stores[i];
                if (_store.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(displayName.ToLower()))
                {
                    store = _store;
                    break;
                }
            }

            rootFolder = store.GetRootFolder();
            folders = rootFolder.Folders;

            for (int i = 1; i < folders.Count; i++)
            {
                mainfolder = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder)folders[i];

                if (mainfolder != null)
                {
                    if (mainfolder.Name.Trim().ToLower() == mainfolderName.Trim().ToLower())
                    {
                        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder f in mainfolder.Folders)
                        {
                            if (f.Name.Trim().ToLower() == folderName.Trim().ToLower())
                            {
                                folder = f;
                                if (subFolderName != "")
                                {
                                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder sub in f.Folders)
                                    {
                                        if (sub.Name.Trim().ToLower() == subFolderName.Trim().ToLower())
                                        {
                                            subfolder = sub;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
```

It successfully get first level - Inbox, Drafts, Archive, Spam, etc. But it does not always get the second level, mainfolder.Folders.Count returns 0. Is there something I missed out? Thank you.

Comment: Can you actually see these folders in Outlook? Have you tried to disable the cached mode?

Comment: Yes, I can see those folders in my Outlook. Disabling cached mode makes Outlook not responding sometime and it is not also possible as per our IT team. I can't figure out why sometimes its working and sometimes not. Does it have to do with internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by pinging the email server before getting the folders in mailbox. This is the solution I found so far, one week now, at least it worked in my case. Thank you.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. Could you please post a code snippet of your solution? Thanks ...

Comment: `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

var ping = new Ping();
var reply = ping.Send("mail.server", 3000);
if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
{
   
}
else
{

}`

Comment: unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. I am trying to access the subfolders of the inbox of an shared inbox. The size is 0, but when I am trying to create a folder that already exists an exception raises. `var i = parentFolder.Folders.OfType<Folder>().Any(f => f.Name == "Test"); // returns always false`. Any ideas?